# Signal in Top Module of a design being driven by two drivers (from different components)

Tags: vhdl

In my design I have several modules. the code snippet of the top module is coming as follows.

There's one problem which confuses me. let's assume the below scenario:

**Step1:**
The Calc1_module works from t1 to t2 and it should send it's output to the input of the memory module to be stored there. (Calc1_out is mapped to **Aggregation_Signal**)

**Step2:**
The Calc2_module works from t3 to t4 and it should send it's output to the input of the memory module to be stored there. (Calc2_out is mapped to **Aggregation_Signal**).

The Memory_Moduel_in is mapped to **Aggregation_Signal**.

Since there are multiple drivers for one signal, it has all the time an unknown value.
It's worth mentioning that all controls occur within FSM to decide when it goes after Calc1 and when Calc2.

How I can selectively interleave different data from different sources on one wire (signal) on at a time -in the top module of the design- without pushing that wire into an unknown state?

In other words, how is it possible to aggregate:

1. value1 for **signal1** (e.g. coming from Calc2 in t1 to t2)
2. value2 from **signal2** (e.g. coming from Calc1 in t2 to t3)

all in one **Aggregation_Signal** without driving it into unknown state.

```
entity TOP is
    port (...);
end entity;

architecture Behav_TOP of TOP is

component FSM is
    port(...);
end component;

component Calc1_Module is
    port
    (   ...
        Calc1_Module_out
        ... );
end component;

component  Calc2_Module is
    port
    (   ...
        Calc2_Module_out
        ... );
end component;

component Memory_Module is
    port
    (   ...
        Memory_Module_in
        ... );
end component;

Signal Aggregation_Signal;

begin

U_FSM : FSM
    port map(...);
U_Calc1_Module : Calc1_Module
    port map
    (   ...
        Calc1_Module_out => Aggregation_Signal,
        ... );
U_Calc2_Module : Calc2_Module
    port map
    ( ...
        Calc2_Module_out => Aggregation_Signal,
        ... );
U_Memory_Module : Memory_Module
    port map
    (   ...
        Memory_Module_in => Aggregation_Signal,
        ... );

end Behav_TOP;
```

Comment: For resolved data types there are functions that resolve data values of one or more drivers. std_logic is a resolved data type. The default resolution function is found in package std_logic_1164, and resolves a logic value and the metavalue 'Z' to the logic value. The metavalue 'Z' signifies a driver is not contributing to the value of a signal. Drivers not contributing the value should be 'Z'. (IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.6 Resolution functions, 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values). (Note your question does not show signal types).

Comment: Otherwise you could use unique names for signal connecting the outputs contributing to `Aggregation_Signal` and infer a multiplexer (e.g. selected signal assignment) or instantiate a multiplexer.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in your term "selectively interleave".

How do you make that selection? Presumably you know when you want to see Calc1, when you want to see Calc2, etc. So encode that information onto a signal, let's call it `Selector`.

Then bring each unit's output onto its own signal, `Calc1_output` etc and use `Selector` to select between them onto `Aggregation_Signal`.

```
Aggregation_Signal <= Calc1_output when Selector = Calc1
                      else Calc2_output when Selector = Calc2
                      else (others => '0';
```

The `Selector` signal can be an enumeration with one value per Calc unit, or a Natural or a std_logic_vector with constants named `Calc1`, `Calc2` etc.

Since you say the calculation is driven by a state machine, it is logical for the state machine to drive `Selector` with the correct value whenever you need a value on `Aggregation_Signal`.